# Best word for Spanish "integral"

Tags: translation, spanish

In Spanish there's a word "*integral*" which, when used as an adjective, means something like "it includes everything".

When we say "servicio integral" we mean that the service includes all aspects related to it. For example, an "integral" service of ecommerce includes consulting, design, coding/development, integration and deployment.

Is there a word in English to describe this kind of service?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Comprehensive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/comprehensive), or [all-encompassing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/all-encompassing)

Comment: In the context of business services, I think "comprehensive service" would be the most common phrase in English. Especially with an additional modifier in there, like "comprehensive accounting services" or "comprehensive building maintenance services".

Answer (score 9):

***Full service***. For example, *full service banking* means the full range of banking services is available. This term is common in many industries: banking, public relations, retail, medicine, even prostitution.

Comment: Should I ask what non-full service prostitution would be? Like, what, they provide the motel room but not the girl?

Comment: Apparently full service means intercourse is included.

Comment: Non-full service means you don't get to cuddle afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

English has *integral* too:

> essential to completeness: constituent *an integral part of the curriculum*
>   lacking nothing essential: entire[¹](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/integral?show=0&t=1341325658)

Comment: Does "integral service" sound right?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan it doesn't sound wrong.

Comment: "integral service" is understandable English, but not idiomatic and possibly confusing, since we have other words like "full" and "comprehensive" that could be used. "Integral" is something of a [false friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) between Spanish and English.

Comment: "Integral sevice" would generally not be used. What "integral" usually means is that one thing is essential to something else (definition one): "A good diet is integral to an athlete's training program." Use of definition two (essentially the Spanish definition) is rare.

Comment: fully-integrated service

Comment: I think in English if you said, "This is an integral service", you would be understood to mean that that service was an essential part of a bigger package of services. If you said, with no introduction, "We offer integral service", people would naturally ask, "What service is that?" and "Integral to what?"

Answer (score 2):

I think that **all inclusive** may correctly translate 'servicio integral'.

Comment: I disagree, "servicio integral" means something among the lines of we take care of all parts of the business and all inclusive, is more for when a hotel or so wants to say that you have all ready paid for everything. You could be a a comprehensive non-all inclusive business.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to comprehensive service, full service and all-inclusive service, other options include:

- end-to-end service (from bumper to bumper or start to finish)

  one-stop service (as opposed to shopping around for each component)

  turnkey/turn-key service (i.e. products with transportation and installation included)